# find().tolistasync() timeout (System.TimeoutException:) in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, exception

I am trying to connect to a mongodb in a virtual machine on CentOS (selinux and firewall are configured). I created a database called test with a collection called test and a view documents in it.
I use C# and the latest relesed driver 2.0.0 in order to connect to the database.
The code looke like this:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;

namespace mongotest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings ();
            settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress ("mongotest", 21017);
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient (settings);

            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<BsonDocument>> datasetsTask = client.GetDatabase ("test").GetCollection<BsonDocument> ("test").Find (x => true).ToListAsync();

            foreach (BsonDocument dataset in datasetsTask.Result) {
                try {
                    Console.WriteLine(dataset["_id"]);
                    try{
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + dataset["test"]);
                    } catch(Exception e) {}
                    try{
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + dataset["name"]);
                    } catch(Exception e) {}
                } catch(Exception e) {Console.WriteLine ("Error: no property called _id");}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked out the database with robomongo. The test database and the test collection are there. In the line where I try to get the result (in the head of the foreach loop) the execution pauses for 30 seconds and then throws a System.TimeoutException (I had to post it into pastebin because it was too long): http://pastebin.com/pp0kfgaH

Down in line 58 is the real error I think. But I don't know how it comes to this server address.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with the connection.

Try setting up the connection just like the "Getting started" example on the Github page:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

Also, remember to add the "mongodb://" to your connection string.